# Creating dataflow classic template to orchestrate the job via DataflowflowTemplatedJobOperator

Tags: java, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create and stage Dataflow Classic template . Following the document in the link provided below -

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#java_8 .

> ***mvn compile exec:java \  -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.myclass \  -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \  --project=PROJECT_ID \   --stagingLocation=gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging \   --templateLocation=gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME   --region=REGION"***

Composer

> ***start_job = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
> task_id="start_job",
> template='gs://bucket/latest/job1',
> parameters={'inputFile': API END POINT, 'output':
> GCS_OUTPUT},
> location='REGION',***

My understanding is first I will have to use maven compile and  deploy the template and  next use json type for passing the parameters to Dataflow templated operator

I am not sure how the parameters and template has to be created . I have manually created dataflow jar file and deployed it to GCS bucket in the past. From the document it looks like the maven compile has to be used to compile and deploy the template and pass the parameter to the job with dataflow java operator .But now with the new design I suppose I have to pass the parameter via Dataflow Templated Job Start Operator.

Has anyone used the Templated method to orchestrate custom Java dataflow job and if yes how is the json file used to pass the arguments. Any example will be very helpful . Currently I am compiling the binary from my local machine and uploading it on bucket.

Appreciate any suggestion to solve the issue.

Regards

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates) for various dataflow template files and stage the template file. Check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) to specify the correct parameters for respective templates. You can create a task within your DAG using the Airflow’s [DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataflow/index.html). Please let me know if it’s helpful.

Comment: Hi @recyclinguy, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven) to deploy Dataflow classic template using mvn compile

You don’t have to store parameters in the json file, you can add  parameters as given below using DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#howto-operator-dataflowtemplatedjobstartoperator).

```
start_template_job = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
    task_id="start-template-job",
    template='gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count',
    parameters={'inputFile': "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt", 'output': GCS_OUTPUT},
    location='europe-west3',
)
```

It is not possible to run MVN just to package and send the jar file to the staging without running the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I created the  Template File from bitbucket repo and created the template in GCS.

```
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.<template-class> \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=<project-id> \
--stagingLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/staging \
--tempLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/temp \
--templateLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/templates/<template-name>.json \
--runner=DataflowRunner"
```

Maven  also required extra parameters to create the template .

Question - Do I need to  Create  json file for passing parameters to template  - ( ie via Create a separate folder  in the template location ) . I think I will be duplicating the parameters again in json file

how do i  to  call the json file in dataflow operator- What goes in  parameter

```
DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator

task_id="start_job",
template='gs://template location', 
parameters={ what should be the  parameters ? should it point to 
           json file},
location= xxx
```

Another question I have is - When we deploy to upper environment especially UAT and PROD, we are not allow to run the pipeline until the allocated schedule time arrives.
So the question is, Is that possible to run MVN just to package and send the jar file to the staging without running the pipeline

Regards

Comment: Hi , Has anyone deployed Dataflow classic template using mvn compile ? If yes how do you set up and orchestrate it in GCP?